# Slonik - slony-I version msimatch

Tags: postgresql, version, slony

I have a DebianEtch/Postgres 8.1 setup which replicates using slony from master > slave.

These servers are being replaced by Debian Squeeze/Postgres 8.4 servers.

I've got Slony between the Squeeze servers running fine, and need to replicate from Etch.Master to Squeeze.Master before I pull the plug on the Etch boxes.

However:

```
./install_ms1_sqz.slonik:6: Possible unsupported PostgreSQL version (80412) 8.4, defaulting to 8.0 support
./install_ms1_sqz.slonik:6: loading of file /usr/share/slony1/slony1_funcs.sql: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR ERROR:  Slonik version: 1.2.6 != Slony-I version in PG build 1.2.21
ERROR:  Slonik version: 1.2.6 != Slony-I version in PG build 1.2.21
```

I'm guessing it's complaining about the different versions of 'something' between Etch and Squeeze servers, but not sure what.

The Etch box is a live server and cannot be disturbed, although I can install a new version of slony if need (and available), and must still replicate to Etch.Slave, although some 'downtime' is OK for this.

So, do I have a hope in hell,  or must I dump/restore the relevant tables, seqs etc at switchover time?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems clear - you have different versions of Slony on the two servers and they aren't compatible.

I'd install both PostgreSQL and Slony from source on the squeeze server - that way you can have the same version on both machines. It's not a difficult process once you've installed the relevant development libraries.

Comment: But isn't the Squeeze version newer than the etch one? The Squeeze has the latest, and I doubt I could (easily) get the latest versions onto Etc.

Comment: See if you can find the same version for both releases.  Backports may be of help here.  Are you familiar with using backports?

Comment: To an extent yes, but not sure if they go back more than one version - and I've then got the problem of going back to the current version on what would then be the live server. I'm thinking that a manual dump/restore will be safer if a real pita!